# How to Joomla 3 use tags on extension?

Tags: joomla-3.x, tags

How to realize tags function on my custom extension? I have try follow https://docs.joomla.org/J3.2:Using_Tags_in_an_Extension this guide step by step but still I can't save tags into database. System alerts "Save failed with the following error:(blank)". I don't know what's the error....

Does Anyone have such experiense on tags development who can help me out?
Thank you !!!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the tags functionality in your custom extension as follows:

1. **models/forms/formfile.xml** -

   `<field name="tagfieldname" type="tag" mode="ajax" label="Tag Field Name" description="" multiple="true" custom="allow" required="true" />`
2. **tables/filename.php** - add the following code in the `bind()` method :

   ```
   public function bind($array, $ignore = '')
   {    
     if (!empty($array['tagfieldname']) ) {
     // Load the tags helper.
     require_once JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_tags/helpers/tags.php';

   // Get the allowed actions for the user
   $canDo = TagsHelper::getActions('com_tags'); // The helper get the user and the component name itself

   // Load the tags model.
   require_once JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_tags/models/tag.php';
   JTable::addIncludePath(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_tags/tables');

   // Get an instance of the table for insertion the new tags
   $tagsModel = TagsModelTag::getInstance('Tag','TagsModel');

   $tags = array(); // Initialization of the tag container must be processed

   // If tags is an array, store-mode
   if ( is_array($array['tagfieldname']) ) {
       // "Allow user creation" mode must be activated (default) in the component creation field
       // Save the tags does not exist into the table tags and get its id for save the entire Item with the proper data
       foreach ($array['tagfieldname'] as $singleTag) {
           // If there is any new tag... create it to get the id and save into the table #__COMPONENT_NAME_TABLE_NAME
           if ( strpos($singleTag, "#new#") !== FALSE ) {
               $user           = JFactory::getUser();
               $userId         = $user->id; // For writing permissions 
               $tagName        = str_replace("#new#", "", $singleTag);
               $tagAlias       = $tagPath = preg_replace('/\W+/', '-', $tagName); // Tags alias filter
               $tagMetadata    = array(
                       "author"=>""
                       , "robots"=>""
                       , "tags"=>null
               );

               // The data tag field row
               $data = array(
                       "parent_id" => 0
                       , "path" => $tagPath
                       , "title" => $tagName
                       , "alias" => $tagAlias
                       , "created_by_alias" => $user
                       , "created_user_id" => $userId
                       , "published" => 1
                       , "checked_out" => 0
                       , "metadata" => json_encode($tagMetadata)
               );

               // Finally, store the tag if the user is granted for that
               if ( $canDo->get('core.create') ) {
                   $table = $tagsModel->getTable();
                   $table->bind($data) ? $table->store($data) : exit;
                   $tags[] = $table->id; // And store the insert_id
               }
           }

       // NOT new Tag (already exists)
       // $singleTag is the tag id
       else
           $tags[] = intval($singleTag);
       }

       // Override the tags array, because we should need to change the id before field saving
       // The field in database will look like "299,345,567,567"
       $array['tagfieldname'] = implode(',', $tags);
   }
   }
   else {
       $array['tagfieldname'] = '';
   }
   return parent::bind($array, $ignore);
   }// bind() ends
   ```

Comment: Thank you!But it still don't work...

Comment: can you tell me what error is it displaying now? Because I have used the same method and it works for me perfectly

Answer (score 1):

For Joomla 3.7.x and every custom component, I took the answer from @liz and put the code in a separate function which you can call from everywhere and use it everywhere you want.

Also I moved the User-factory above the foreach, because we just need to call it once, not for every loop.
And I removed the `$canDo`, because it is not working, as `TagsHelper` is not available like this. Perhaps this can be done with any other access-control-check?

```
function saveJoomlaTags($tags, $created_by_alias="", $note="") {

        // Load the tags model.
            require_once JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_tags/models/tag.php';
            JTable::addIncludePath(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_tags/tables');

        // Get an instance of the table for insertion the new tags
            $tagsModel = TagsModelTag::getInstance('Tag','TagsModel');

        // If tags is not an array, return nothing.
            if ( !is_array($tags) ) {
                return "";
            } 

        $user = JFactory::getUser();
        $return = array();

        // "Allow user creation" mode must be activated (default) in the component creation field
        // Save the tags does not exist into the table tags and get its id for save the entire Item with the proper data
            foreach ($tags as $singleTag) {
                // every custom-entered tag starts with "#new#", every exsting tag is the ID.
                    if ( !strBeginsWith($singleTag, "#new#")) { // see pm_helper.
                        $return[] = intval($singleTag);
                        continue;
                    }

                // A new Tag must be saved to the DB first.
                    $tagName        = str_replace("#new#", "", $singleTag);
                    $tagAlias       = $tagPath = preg_replace('/\W+/', '-', $tagName); // Tags alias filter
                    $tagMetadata    = array();
                    $tagMetadata["author"]  = "";
                    $tagMetadata["robots"]  = "";
                    $tagMetadata["tags"]    = "";


                // The data tag field row
                    $data = array(
                            "parent_id" => 0
                            , "path" => $tagPath
                            , "title" => $tagName
                            , "alias" => $tagAlias
                            , "created_by_alias" => $created_by_alias
                            , "created_user_id" => $user->id
                            , "published" => 1
                            , "language" => "*"
                            , "checked_out"=> 0
                            , "metadata" => json_encode($tagMetadata)
                            , "note" => $note
                    );

                // Finally, store the tag if the user is granted for that
                    $table = $tagsModel->getTable();
                    $table->bind($data) ? $table->store($data) : print "Fehler beim Speichern der Tags. Siehe ".__FILE__.__LINE__;
                    $return[] = $table->id; // And store the insert_id                       

            } // foreach 

        // Override the tags array, because we should need to change the id before field saving
        // The field in database will look like "299,345,567,567"
            $return = implode(',',$return);

        return $return; // a list of IDs.

    } // saveItemTags()
```

You will also need this helper function "strBeginsWith":

```
    function strBeginsWith($str, $beginsWith) {
       if (strpos($str, $beginsWith) === 0) {
           return true;
       }
       return false;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there is something wrong with your `#__content_types` entries.

First of all, you need to register your content_types for your views, as described here:

- [**Using Tags in an Extension**](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Using_Tags_in_an_Extension)

Then you need to be careful with the values of the fields of your content_types.

More specifically for saving tags into the `#__contentitem_tag_map` table for your extension, the required fields for your content_type are:

`type_id`, `type_title`, `type_alias`, `table`, `field_mappings`

From these fields make sure that the `type_alias` and the `field_mappings` contain valid data. For example a simple syntax error in `field_mappings` would lead to errors, like the one you got.